# How can we pass e.channel Uri to a web service from windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

```
void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
        {

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Display the new URI for testing purposes.   Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                //    e.ChannelUri.ToString()));

                ServiceReference1.Service1Client objServiceClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();


                objServiceClient.InsertNotificationURLCompleted +=
                    new EventHandler<InsertNotificationURLCompletedEventArgs>(


            });
        }
```

In the above code, ServiceReference1 is my Web Service, now I want to send e.channel uri to the web service. How can I pass this uri to the web service?

Comment: If i guess right there is also a method like 'InsertNotificationURL' in your web service, that takes a string

Comment: Finally i done it. 1st we have to create object to our service as below. **Service.Service1Client object=new Service.Service1Client();** Next we will pass the URI to the web service as **Object.InsertNotificationUrlAsync(string.Format(e.channeluri.ToString()));**